# Apache Kafka PubSub

Tags: apache-kafka

**How does the pubsub work in Kafka?**

I was reading about Kafka Topic-Partition theory, and it mentioned that `In one consumer group, each partition will be processed by one consumer only.` Now there are 2 cases:-

1. If the producer didn't mention the partition key or message key, the message will be evenly distributed across the partitions of a specific topic. ---- If this is the case, and there can be only one consumer(or subscriber in case of PubSub) per partition, how does all the subscribers receive the similar message?
2. If I producer produced to a specific partition, then how does the other consumers (or subscribers) receive the message?

How does the PubSub works in each of the above cases? if only a single consumer can get attached to a specific partition, how do other consumers receive the same msg?

Answer (score 0):

Kafka prevents more than one consumer *in a group* from reading a single partition. If you have a use-case where multiple consumers in a consumer group need to process a particular event, then Kafka is probably the wrong tool. Otherwise, you need to write code external to Kafka API to transmit one consumer's events to other services via other protocols. Kafka Streams Interactive Query feature (with an RPC layer) is one example of this.

Or you would need lots of unique consumers groups to read the same event.

Answer doesn't change when producers send data to a specific partitions since "evenly distributed" partitions are still *pre-computed*, as far as the consumer is concerned. The consumer API is assigned to specific partitions, and does not coordinate the assignment with any producer.